# Can Android Visualizer Class be used on SoundPool object?

Tags: android, fft, sessionid, soundpool, visualizer

When using a SoundPool audio class, it definitely has some advantages over a MediaPlayer when just playing short audio clips. The two I've noticed is SoundPool is a lot faster. MediaPlayer can lag a bit on startup and it's much easier to go from one sound clip to the next, where I don't have to stop,reset,prepare each time.

However, is it possible to use the visualizer to get real time fft data from audio data playing in the SoundPool like it is for MediaPlayer? I couldn't come across any topics that cover that, but by the off chance I thought I would ask because it seems like it should be possible. The documentation says, *"The SoundPool library uses the MediaPlayer service to decode the audio into a raw 16-bit PCM mono or stereo stream."* So if I could reference the MediaPlayer that SoundPool is using then I think I could just use `getAudioSessionId()` perhaps?

I already tried setting session ID to 0 to just get the output mix. It didn't work but it's not really the ideal effect that I am looking for anyway. Also one of the first things I did was try using the loaded SoundPool SoundID in place of the visualizers session ID, but that also didn't work.